# How store event.width in a variable in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a script that displays the dimensions of the tkinter window and I was wondering how I can set those values into a variable?

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import PhotoImage

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def canvas_changed(event):
    global WW
    WW = event.width
    global HH
    HH = event.height

img = PhotoImage(file="competeButton.png")
foo = canvas.create_image(image=img, width=WW, height=HH)
foo.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you want `event.width` as a variable?

Comment: yeah. if you run this program you will see that it displays {width} x {height}. I am trying to get those values stored in a variable so that WW = {width} and HH = {height}

Comment: whats wrong in saying `WW = event.width` and `HH = event.height` inside the function?

Comment: I tried that but when I create an image and set width=WW and height=HH, it says "name 'WW' is not defined'

Comment: @Haversine include a code where that is used?

Comment: `canvas_changed()` has never been executed, so `WW` and `HH` will not be created.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special you have to do. Data is data, whether it comes from a widget or a database or anything else.

Here's an example that saves the value to a global variable:

```
def canvas_changed(event):
    global canvas_width
    canvas_width = event.width
```

Comment: I am still getting the error "name WW is not defined". I have updated my question with the code

Comment: @Haversine: that's because you're using `WW` before the function is called for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with all your image and the resizing of it. Then issue an if statement to call those values every time it changes. Here is an example of what you might do:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class MainFrame(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r"competeButton.png"))
        self.canvas_img = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=self.img)

    def resize(self, event):
        img = Image.open(r"competeButton.png").resize((event.width, event.height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.canvas_img, image=self.img)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_frame = MainFrame()
    main_frame.mainloop()
```